# How to solve malformed URL error while making JasperReports pdf file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to print to a pdf file using jasper reports; a list of results fetched from the database. I am getting a null pointer exception / malformed URL error now when the program tries to make the report.

I've run this piece of code a few times and it has worked before, but not now. I'm running this on an Ubuntu box (18.04). I've tried debugging and tried altering the code a few times now. I've also run some system.out some places to see if the input is going through or not.

### SalaryController.java

```
@GetMapping(value = "/salary/reports/{id}/{month}")
public void report(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable 
Long id, @PathVariable Long month) throws Exception {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    System.out.println(id+"---------"+month);
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSrc = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportGenerationServiceImpl.generateMonthlyReport(id, month));
    //JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportGenerationServiceImpl.generateMonthlyReport(id, month));
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/payslip.jrxml");

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, dataSrc);
    try {

    File pdf = File.createTempFile("payslip", ".pdf",new File("/home/foo/Documents"));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, new FileOutputStream(pdf));

    HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance());
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(response.getWriter()));
    exporter.exportReport();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

}

### payslip-report.jrxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="payslip" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="d8f2655e-ef65-49cc-90cc-a08385cad0fd">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="ReportDataSet" uuid="193ed9cd-3d2b-4858-9cca-d21a951019a2">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Mysql Data Adapter "/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[Select * from payslip.salary]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="basic" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="hra" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="otherAllowances" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="taxDeductions" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="netSalary" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="month" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <background>
        <band height="1" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="123" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="140" y="0" width="415" height="110" backcolor="#0C4ACF" uuid="2575eb12-f718-4332-a349-e5fbeee62958"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="140" height="110" uuid="32ad2748-1f14-4ac5-a9df-91670ab327d4"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="430" y="0" width="125" height="110" forecolor="#F0F0F0" uuid="97d884db-2ed2-49e3-a4fa-652031fbcc59"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Confidential]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="140" y="0" width="290" height="50" forecolor="#F0F0F0" uuid="386c4505-43e3-47d6-8893-3fd8faa150c5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Payslip Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="240" y="50" width="100" height="30" forecolor="#F0F0F0" uuid="323333dd-7e41-4518-816d-e765c5e9c6d6"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{month}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="29" forecolor="#F0F0F0" backcolor="#0C4ACF" uuid="51ec09f9-1c6d-45c8-bcae-4c4c395621b7"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Description]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="240" y="0" width="160" height="29" forecolor="#F0F0F0" backcolor="#0C4ACF" uuid="06e52895-7d44-4c5b-aec4-9a1a8315b04b"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Salary]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="400" y="0" width="155" height="29" forecolor="#F0F0F0" backcolor="#0C4ACF" uuid="f2eddb9e-c8ca-4061-bf3e-4ee15f0df991"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Deductions]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="231" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="231" uuid="78d0820a-8cbd-4536-8b9a-a2efaaca7df5"/>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="399" y="0" width="1" height="231" uuid="9bdaf357-20d3-4148-977a-ce68e7ddef06"/>
                </line>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="240" y="0" width="1" height="232" uuid="406a057f-6d73-4830-8689-d378c4e0ba68"/>
                </line>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d0e0164b-793c-4fe9-9e2d-e2f1aeeff9fb"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Basic Salary]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="241" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="94a0e1bc-9650-45b1-8a52-2896568eaf1c"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{basic}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="e59e744f-e514-48bb-b47e-d8d06b7db272"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[HRA]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="240" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="9510ee9e-3938-48a6-9242-0844eb99e705"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{hra}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="62" width="100" height="30" uuid="946bcc0f-9730-4881-abd4-fdbbf6ca9e8d"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Other Allowances]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="240" y="62" width="100" height="30" uuid="3c55b1e5-4a62-417e-838c-f940d354b553"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{otherAllowances}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="100" height="30" uuid="90ee3fc0-fca8-4b8d-8eed-7abdd3f80974"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Tax Deductions]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="400" y="97" width="100" height="30" uuid="8c36f0c9-2053-4231-a23b-6501afd9285a"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{taxDeductions}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="-1" y="207" width="556" height="25" forecolor="#F0F0F0" backcolor="#0C4ACF" uuid="816a2afe-9b04-46ef-99a4-ce3bae3530e3"/>
                </rectangle>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="210" width="241" height="21" forecolor="#F0F0F0" uuid="8b64e3c7-af3d-44fe-9702-8c51f0e5011f"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Net Salary]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="399" y="207" width="156" height="24" forecolor="#F0F0F0" uuid="b88e8ba1-ab37-4548-b606-766516b4ce8f"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{netSalary}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="-1" y="232" width="556" height="1" uuid="1d9c5abd-5b53-4aa5-bde9-5f690d74ac8f"/>
                </line>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="340" y="0" width="215" height="30" uuid="a3d54f19-0e4c-48f8-a01b-0436f3cb8a78"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

While I should be getting a pdf file with the results in it, I am getting this as a result :

```
1--------------------------9
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:532) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:620) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:806) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892) ~[commons-digester-2.1.jar:2.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:297) ~[jasperreports-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:284) ~[jasperreports-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:273) ~[jasperreports-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:247) ~[jasperreports-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:338) ~[jasperreports-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:605) ~[jasperreports-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.synprox.controller.SalaryController.report(SalaryController.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging, I have solved the problem on my own.
Here's how I did it. After debugging, the error seemed to lie in the

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/payslip.jrxml");
```

So looking over the imports, I found that I erroneously imported the jasper reports library whereas it was supposed to be `java.io.InputStream` instead.